# WooCommerce Subscriptions and Yith My Account Issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_status() on null

I have WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions installed as well as YITH WooCommerce Customize My Account Page. And when I click on View Subscription, I get an error about the website having issues. When I show console in Chrome, and/or enable Debug, I get the following error message. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_status() on null in /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/templates/myaccount/subscription-details.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(249): include() #1 /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wcs-template-loader.php(41): wc_get_template('myaccount/subsc...', Array, '', '/www/wp-content...') #2 /wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WCS_Template_Loader::get_subscription_details_template(NULL) #3 /wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4 /wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/templates/myaccount/view-subscription.php(23): do_action('woocommerce_sub...', NULL) #6 /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(249): include('/www/wp-content...') #7 /www/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-customize-myaccount-page/includes/functio in /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/templates/myaccount/subscription-details.php on line 18

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your view-subscription.php file:

```
$subscription = wcs_get_subscription(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

You can find it in inside the folder woocommerce/myaccount of your theme. If you don't have it then you will have to create it by copying it from your woocommerce installation (check [this link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) if you are not sure how it works).

That line should go just after the security check:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
```